# Jointjs Hello World blank with no error in console

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I created this based on their tut http://jointjs.com/tutorial

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

 </head>
 <body>
<div id="myholder" >

</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="joint.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="joint.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myholder'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1
    });

    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });

    var rect2 = rect.clone();
    rect2.translate(300);

    var link = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id }
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

But I can't see anything and no error console. If I moved include at the end, I get error joint unknown.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the created rectangles and the link to your graph.

Add this line at the end of your script.

```
graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh my, thanks, I was doing so on windows tablet with my finger it didn't select the last line I did not realize :)